# How to load Tensorflow frozen graph model from Google bucket?

Tags: tensorflow, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage

Locally when we want to load model using TensorFlow we do this:

```
path_to _frozen = model_path + '/frozen_inference_graph.pb'
detection_graph = tf.Graph()
with detection_graph.as_default():
    od_graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
    with tf.io.gfile.GFile(path_to _frozen, 'rb') as fid:
        serialized_graph = fid.read()
        od_graph_def.ParseFromString(serialized_graph)
        tf.import_graph_def(od_graph_def, name='')
```

How we can load a stored model on google bucket using google cloud function?

Comment: When you load loacally, what is the local path ? something like `/home/user`?

Comment: yeah, something like that. By the way, I meant if there is another function like "tf.MetaGraphDef" or I need to use meta or index checkpoints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store your pb file in storage.

Then, in your function, download it in the [local writable directory `/tmp`](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/exec#file_system). Remember, this directory is "in memory". This mean that the memory allocated to your function has to be well defined to handle your app memory footprint AND your model downloaded file

Replace your first line by something like this.

```
# Be sure that your function service account as access to the storage bucket    
storage_client = storage.Client()
bucket = storage_client.get_bucket('<bucket_name>')
blob = bucket.blob('<path/to>/frozen_inference_graph.pb')

# Download locally your pb file
path_to_frozen = '/tmp/frozen_inference_graph.pb'
blob.download_to_filename(path_to_frozen)
```

Comment: I tried to load frozen_graph.pb but when I wanna test the function I get this error:Error: function crashed. Details:
Expected binary or unicode string, got None

Comment: Did you check if the file was well downloaded? like a print of the file content or something like this? I also performed a typo error in my example (space between path_to and _frozen). I corrected it in my example, be sure that isn't your issue.

Comment: Yes, I tested and the model is downloaded but then I try to use it like this:  detection_graph = tf.Graph()
 with detection_graph.as_default():
  od_graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
  with tf.io.gfile.GFile(blob.download_to_filename(PATH_TO_FROZEN_GRAPH), 'rb') as fid:
   serialized_graph = fid.read()
   od_graph_def.ParseFromString(serialized_graph)
   tf.import_graph_def(od_graph_def, name='') , which shows that error

Comment: You don't have an error line to localized the issue?

Comment: I just found the problem, I tweaked my function to be this: def handler(request):
 download_blob(BUCKET_NAME,'redbull/output_inference_graph.pb/frozen_inference_graph.pb','/tmp/frozen_inference_graph.pb')
 print("okay")
 detection_graph = tf.Graph()
 with detection_graph.as_default():
  od_graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
  with tf.io.gfile.GFile('/tmp/frozen_inference_graph.pb', 'rb') as fid:
   serialized_graph = fid.read()
   od_graph_def.ParseFromString(serialized_graph)
   tf.import_graph_def(od_graph_def, name='') and now it is working

Answer (score 2):

```
def download_blob(bucket_name, source_blob_name, destination_file_name):
storage_client = storage.Client()
bucket = storage_client.get_bucket(bucket_name)
blob = bucket.blob(source_blob_name)
blob.download_to_filename(destination_file_name)
```

def handler(request):
    download_blob(BUCKET_NAME,'redbull/output_inference_graph.pb/frozen_inference_graph.pb','/tmp/frozen_inference_graph.pb')
    print("okay")
    detection_graph = tf.Graph()
    with detection_graph.as_default():
        od_graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
        with tf.io.gfile.GFile('/tmp/frozen_inference_graph.pb', 'rb') as fid:
            serialized_graph = fid.read()
            od_graph_def.ParseFromString(serialized_graph)
            tf.import_graph_def(od_graph_def, name='')